# Momentum calculated from angle? Javascript

Tags: javascript

So Im working on a project in javascript and need to set x momentum and y momentum based on the angle. So say there is a 45 degree angle it would set the x momentum and the y momentum to 20 each so it goes in a line. How would I got about converting any angle in either degrees or radians into momentum?

Comment: Try trigonometry(sin and cos specifically, one will give x, the other y)

Comment: Also note that direction is context sensitive. In a geographic context, 0° is up and bearings increase clockwise. In mathematics, 0° is horizontal to the right (equivalent to geographic 90° or due east) and increase anti–clockwise. So 45° and 225° are the same direction for both, but all other directions are not. ECMAScript uses the mathematic sense.

Answer (score 2):

To use `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`, you have to convert degree to radian:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin
>   `Math.sin(x)`: `x` - a number (given in radians)

If you have radian, then you can use `Math.cos` to calculate the `X` factor and `Math.sin` to calculate the `Y` factor.

```js
function degreeToRadian(degree)
{
  return degree * Math.PI / 180;
}

function getMomentumFactors(radian)
{
  return {x:Math.cos(radian),y:Math.sin(radian)};
}

var example = getMomentumFactors(degreeToRadian(45));
var momentum = 20;
console.log('x',momentum*example.x,'y',momentum*example.y)
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that rounding should probably be applied. A direction of 180° should give `y 0` but due to ECMAScript numbers following IEEE 754 gives `y 2.4492935982947065e-15` which is *nearly* zero but not quite. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @RobG, rounding makes sense indeed :)

Comment: Thanks :D sorry my Maths class has not gone through trigonometry yet :/